# Jar files on Solaris listed as corrupt, fine on Windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, solaris

Using ant build scripts in eclipse to create a tar file using the following command

Build is run on a Windows 32-bit machine and the resulting tar is unpacked on a Solaris 32-bit machine.  When the main class is executed, the jar files (both those built from code and those per-packaged FOSS jars are reported as corrupt.  I can use winzip to unpack the tar file and again to open any one of the jar files and they open without complaint.  Any suggestions as to possible solutions?

Comment: Probably getting corrupted in the process of moving from windows to solaris -- perhaps you're treating them as text files and munging line endings?

Comment: Are the .jar files checked into some source repository from the Windows side that might be corrupting them because they were checked in as text instead of binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a way to run checksums (e.g. - md5sum) on the tars/jars?  If the checksums match, you have an interesting problem.  If the checksums differ, something corrupted your files in transit from Widows to Unix.  Likely culprit is transferring the files as text instead of binary, but I don't knows how the files were moved between computers.